# How to select common titles from table?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

So I'm creating a movie site, where you can create your own list, in which you can add the movies you've already watched, you plan to watch etc.

On my site you have the opportunities to visit the profile of other users, and see their list, and you could check what are those movies that are present both in yours, and the visited user's list.

So, say I have a table called list, with 2 columns: username(the user who has added the movie to his list) and title(obviously the title of the movie)

I have a few records in this table, like :

*John*|*Movie1*

*John*|*Movie5*

*Patrick*|*Movie1*

*Patrick*|*Movie2*

*John*|*Movie3*

*Patrick*|*Movie3*

*John*|*Movie6*

*Patrick*|*Movie7*

*John*|*Movie2*

In this example, Movie1, Movie2 and Movie3 are the common movies on Patrick's and John's list

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT title FROM list WHERE 
(SELECT title FROM list WHERE username="Patrick")
=
(SELECT title FROM list WHERE username="John")
```

But this doesn't work, it returns with the following error: *Subquery returns with more than 1 row*

I would appreciate if someone could provide a solution!

Comment: thats would  be a simple intersect i guess!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JOIN on same table

```
SELECT l.title 
FROM list l
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT title 
  FROM list WHERE username='Patrick'
) t1 on t1.title = l.title 
inner join  (
  SELECT title 
  FROM list 
  WHERE username='John' 
) t2 on t2.title = l.title
```

or (same query in compact way)

```
SELECT l.title 
FROM list l
INNER JOIN  list l1  on l.title = l1.title  
    AND  l1.username='Patrick'
INNER JOIN list l2 on l.title = l2.title 
    AND l2.username='John'
```

Comment: Simply: `select title from (...'Patrick') p join (...'John') j using (title);`

Comment: The other answers are correct as well, but in the end this is the one I found the best solution for my problem. Thank you! I didn't know I can join on the same table too

Comment: if you are interesed  .. i have updated the answer  adding a more compact way ..  too

Answer (score 2):

You can `group by title` for all the movies they both like and get only those for which `having count(*) = 2` is true, meaning that they both like:

```
select title 
from tablename
where username in ('Patrick', 'John')
group by title
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Subquery Based, Find all John Movie title which is in Patrick Movie Title. [demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/enbQvx2hwPikFehenBQCKH/0)

```sql
SELECT title 
FROM demo 
WHERE username="Patrick" AND title IN
    (SELECT title 
     FROM demo 
     WHERE username="John");
```